# Formidable couldn't parse large file

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, formidable

Below code works with the small files, but could upload files that is more than 50kb. I think there is something I should setting with the maxFileSize. I'm using [Uppy](https://uppy.io/) at the client. After I console.log in the server, actually it does do the request. I don't get any clue in the Stackoverflow, really need help.

```
const upload = (req, res) => {
    // formidable : to parse html form data
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm({ multiples: true, maxFileSize: 10000 * 1024 * 1024 })
    const d = new Date();
    // I have console.log here and everything seems fine
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.log('err', err)      // returns nothing
        console.log('files', files) // returns nothing
        console.log('fields', fields) // returns nothing
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error parsing the files");
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "There was an error parsing the files",
                status: "Fail",
                error: err
            })
        }
        for (let file in files) {
            try {
                if (files[file]) {
                    let oldPath = files[file]['path']
                    let rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath)

                    const month = parseInt(d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + parseInt(d.getMonth() + 1) : parseInt(d.getMonth() + 1)

                    let today = `${d.getFullYear()}_${month}_${d.getDate()}`
                    let folderPath = __basedir + `\\media\\uploads\\storage\\${today}\\`;
                    // folderPath = ..\dashboard-v2.0\server\\media\uploads\storage\\2021_06_18\\

                    if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
                        fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, {
                            recursive: true
                        });
                    }

                    // newPath =..\dashboard-v2.0\server\\media\uploads\storage\\2021_06_18\\WIN.jpg
                    let newPath = folderPath + files[file]['name']
                    let databasePath = `storage/${today}/${files[file]['name']}`;
                    let filename =  files[file]['name'] // example_files.zip

                    if (fs.existsSync(newPath)){
                        // if file is existed then add Date.now()
                        let time =  Date.now()
                        let filenameSplit = filename.split('.')
                        
                        filename = filenameSplit[0] + '_' + time + '.' + filenameSplit[1] 
                        // filename = WIN_1626750408096.jpg

                        newPath = folderPath + filename
                        databasePath = `storage/${today}/${filename}`;
                    }
                    
                    fs.writeFile(newPath, rawData, async (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return res.status(400).send({ "err": err })
                        }

                        const userToken = jwt.verify(fields.user, config.TOKEN_SECRET)

                        const newFiles = {
                            filename: filename,
                            user_id: ObjectId(userToken.id),
                            filepath: databasePath,
                            added_time: Date.now(),
                        }

                        const result = await db.collection("ate_files").insertOne(newFiles)
                        console.log(`Created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`)

                        console.log(`Successfull upload ${newPath}`);
                    })
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
                return res.status(409).send({ "error": `${err}` })
            }
        }
        
    })

    return res.status(200).send({ "message": "Successfully uploadded the files" })
}
```

Comment: your return res.status(200).send({ "message": "Successfully uploadded the files" }) is too soon, it should be in the callback

Comment: Hi @WalleCyril thank you for helping me out! You're right ! My problem is because the `return res.status(200).send({ "message": "Successfully uploadded the files" })` is too early. Thank you very much, do you mind to write it as solution? or I just could answering by refering to you and checklist Community Wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return res.status(200).send({ "message": "Successfully uploadded the files" }) is too soon, it should be in the callback.

It could be problematic on large files since the beginning of the big file would be received and then the client already receives a response which could logically cut the connection in http